# BSD Make substitution fails in rule $(objdir)/%o: %c

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

I'm trying to write a portable BSD and GNU Makefile that does an out-of-source build and automatic prerequisites.  GNU Make works fine but BSD Make does not.

```
OBJDIR := objdir
SRCS := foo.c bar.c baz.c
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
CPPFLAGS += -MMD -MP

all: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o main $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

-include $(OBJDIR)/$(SRCS:%.c=%.d)

clean:
    rm -rf main $(OBJDIR)
```

This is the output:

```
$ gmake
mkdir objdir
cc  -MMD -MP  -c -o objdir/foo.o foo.c
cc  -MMD -MP  -c -o objdir/bar.o bar.c
cc  -MMD -MP  -c -o objdir/baz.o baz.c
cc  -o main objdir/foo.o objdir/bar.o objdir/baz.o
$ bmake
--- objdir ---
bmake: bmake: don't know how to make objdir/foo.o. Stop

bmake: stopped in /home/antonin/tests
```

My guess is that BSD Make does not understand substitution within a path (is that the right term?) `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c`, because `bmake OBJDIR=.` works fine. If so, how can I write a simple, portable Makefile that achieves the same functionality?

[Example for testing](https://gist.github.com/MisterDA/e5f713761c06896a33e8606eccfd4fb0).

Thank you!

Comment: Pattern rules is a feature of GNU Make which wasn't available in BSD Make last time I looked at it.  BSD Make really want to build in the current directory.  You could perhaps do what you want using `VPATH` which I think is comment to BSD and GNU make, but you'd  either have to invoke make in the destination directory or reinvoke make automatically in the destination directory (something I'm not sure that it is possible to achieve in a portable way).

Comment: _how can I write a simple, portable Makefile that achieves the same functionality?_  Short answer: you can't.  You can write a makefile that gets the similar result in a very different way (as mentioned by AProgrammer, running the build in the object directory instead).

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you answered because I've been dissecting the articles on your blog for some time. I'm going to give up on out-of-source build for bmake. Thanks!

Comment: If you want write portable `Makefile` you should read this: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html  You can use only these features.

Comment: I've managed to write a Makefile that I'm more-or-less satisfied with; but I'd like to fiddle with `VPATH` like this: `mkdir build; cd build; make VPATH=.. -f ../Makefile`. However, I have some scripts at the root of my project that generate header files. They're launched with `./script.sh > header.h`, and Make can't launch them since the working directory is now `build` instead of the root of the project. Is there a way to fix this? Prepend `VPATH`?